# All usernames are indicated by the username phrase

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

admin dashboard:

[image]

In addition to the admin part, the template is displayed in the same way.

Ever since I customized the accounts section, in all the sections where I have used the username, there is a problem that the usernames are displayed without that name and only by displaying the phrase username.

settings.py:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomUser'
```

models.py(accounts):

```
class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, username, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address.")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a username.")
        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
            password=password,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


def get_profile_image_filepath(self, filepath):
    return f'images/accounts/profiles/{self.pk}/{"profile.png"}'


class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    class Meta:
        permissions = [
            ('all', 'all of the permissions')
        ]

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email', max_length=100, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=55, unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to=get_profile_image_filepath, default='images/accounts/profiles/default_image.jpg')

    objects = MyAccountManager()


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.USERNAME_FIELD

    def get_profile_image_filename(self):
        return str(self.profile_image)[str(self.profile_image).index(f'images/accounts/profiles/{self.pk}/'):]

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("accounts:user_view", args=[str(self.id)])
```

models.py(news):

```
class News(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        permissions = [
            ('all', 'all of the permissions')
        ]
        ordering = ['-date']

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    header_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/news/header/")
    body = RichTextUploadingField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, default='cryptocurrency', related_name='category')
    like_news = models.ManyToManyField(AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name='the_news')
    unlike_news = models.ManyToManyField(AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name='the_news_unlike')

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.like_news.count()

    def total_unlikes(self):
        return self.unlike_news.count()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("news_detail", args=[str(self.id)])
```

Which part of the code is wrong that shows the username like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return `self.username`, not <s>`self.USERNAME_FIELD`</s>:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    # …
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

or if you want to return the attribute with the `USERNAME_FIELD`, you can use the [**`getattr(…)`** function [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    # …
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

    def __str__(self):
        return getattr(self, self.USERNAME_FIELD)
```